# how to trim quotation marks on a variable?

Tags: php

I'm new to php so please no bullying. I have the following and I can't trim the quotation mrks around the name of my variable. For some reason the following displays "Workaholics", why ? 
I'm using a library to scrape IMDB and all my titles come back with those quotation marks in my $movieArray.

Thanks.

```
 $movieArray["title"] = '"Workaholics"';

 echo trim($movieArray["title"], '"');
```

So this works but it doesn't work below:

```
    $imdb = new Imdb();
    $movieArray = $imdb->getMovieInfo("Workaholics");
    {
        echo trim($movieArray["title"], '"');
        echo $movieArray["poster"];

    }
```

Where  $movieArray["poster"] = '"Workaholics"'... That doesn't work, trim doesn't work either.

Output:

```
"Workaholics"
```

Comment: That's not even valid PHP

Comment: `""Workaholics""` would be a syntax error here. Assuming you have the string `"Workaholics"` (so, you could assign it here with `'"Workaholics"'`), your trim _should_ work, unless there are (perhaps not-visible, or whitespace like space, tab, newline) characters in front & after that string.

Comment: @vishakvkt: have you looked at the second argument of `trim()` in your link?

Comment: @wrikken, oops, din't see it. Should delete the wrong comment.

Comment: yes, sorry, I have this: '"Workaholics"'

Comment: You seem to be getting a lot of nonsense alternatives here. As you're starting I feel the need to confirm you're _right_ in using the `trim()` statement no matter what kind of nonsense goes on here below, it's just a matter of finding out _why_ your trim fails (so, more characters before or after the `"`'s).

Comment: Yes, that was my thought. But I checked and when I print out the variable, it doesn't seem to have any white space or anything that suggests why the trim() would fail.

Comment: Are you sure the quote characters are `"`, and not fancy quotes like `“` or `”`?

Comment: "Workaholics" that's what it prints out. Edit: No, I just checked with copy pasting, and nothing.

Comment: Could it be the function  $arr['title'] = trim($this->match('/<title>(IMDb \- )*(.*?) \(.*?<\/title>/ms', $html, 2)); ??

Answer (score 0):

This will be enough

```
   $movieArray["title"] = "Workaholics";

     echo trim($movieArray["title"]);
```

Comment: I think his question was bad, he meant to write `'"Workaholics"'` or equivalent, so this is not an answer